# Three digit year datetime returns an error

Tags: php, datetime

I have the following code:

`new DateTime("20-01-123");`

Why does it return an error?

`Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (20-01-123) at position 8 (3): Unexpected character in [...]`

Meanwhile, the `checkdate()` function accepts the year as it is a number 1-32767.

Comment: You _do_ mean to create the year 123, relatively shortly after Jesus' birth…?

Comment: [`DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', "20-01-123");`](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLSyUlsSRVwVbBBUiFZOamWlklF6UC2W5F@blu@UW5iSUa6im6ubqR6joKSkYGugaGuoZGxkqa1lypyRn5CmDtunZpKCo1rf//BwA)

Comment: There's no way to guess the format if all three figures can be any size. I suggest you stick to YYYY-MM-DD everywhere (e.g. `new DateTime('0123-01-20')`). There's no point in using regional settings unless you're displaying something to the user.

Comment: Refer from [PHP document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php). The `\DateTime` class constructor accept first argument as [date and time formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php). The most close formats that you use is in [**Date formats**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) link. There are no 3 digits year to be accepted, just 2 or 4 as mentioned by @ÁlvaroGonzález